# C# Data Loss between windows

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, nullreferenceexception

In order to navigate my application you are presented with the Mainwindow on load up. There is a button that you can click that opens the TeacherTools window. From here you are able to add new students to the list. On this window I have a back button that will return you to the MainWindow and I can confirm that the information is still usable here. I'm having an issue whereby I open a 3rd window which is a Exam window in which students are presented with questions afterwards and their score should be added to the currently loaded Student visa his name.

```
private List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    TeacherTools teachTools = new TeacherTools();
    Learning myLearning = new Learning();

    private void teachAdmin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        teachTools.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }

    private void Selection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        myTest.studentName.Text = studentsList.SelectedValue.ToString();
        myTest.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }

}

//Exam Window
public partial class Test : Window
{
    //I'm sure its not this
    Student loadedStudent = new Student();
    TeacherTools teachTools = new TeacherTools();

    public void(private void finishTest()
    {

        loadedStudent = teachTools.Kids.Find(delegate(Student s) { return s.Name == studentName.Text; }); //This line 
        loadedStudent.Attempted = true;
        loadedStudent.Score = score;
    }
}
```

As such i'm getting a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - NullReferenceException". I'm not sure why this is happening because I can make modifications to a Student object from the MainWindow.

Edit: TeacherTools Class

```
public partial class TeacherTools : Window
{
    private List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

    public TeacherTools()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<Student> Kids
    {
       get { return studentList; }
       //set { studentList = value; }
    }

    private void newStudentClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.Name = nameBox.Text;
        studentList.Add(student);
        studentData.ItemsSource = studentList;
        studentData.Items.Refresh();
        //nameBox
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when you open the `Test` window you are creating a new instance of the `TeacherTools` window, which means there are no elements in the `Kids` list. If this is the way you wanted to accomplish this, you could set the `TeacherTools` instance in the `Test` window as a public property and pass the object from the main window, like so:

```
//Test Window
public partial class Test : Window
{
    Student loadedStudent = new Student();
    public TeacherTools teachTools { get; set; }
    ...
}

//Main Window
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ...

    private void Selection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        myTest.teachTools = this.teachTools;
        myTest.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this, but I think this is the approach you are looking for. I will also say that you could be playing a dangerous game by passing the different windows between each other instead of using a class to handle this.

Comment: I think I understand what you did, Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad my answer was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

In your window named "Test" you are using the object teachTools but you haven't created this anywhere.

You do have a similarly named object in your MainWindow, but this is not shared with the Test-window. You should also create a new instance in the Test-window

Comment: Sorry I had made a mistake while copying but I'm doing that anyway see above for update.

Comment: Could you show us the TeacherTools-class? Also, which object is actually throwing the NullReference then?

Comment: This "loadedStudent = teachTools.Kids.Find(delegate(Student s) { return s.Name == studentName.Text; });" I've added the TeacherTools Class.

Answer (score 1):

Either studentList contains an item that is null (which would cause the s.Name part to throw), or studentName is null (which would cause the studentName.Text part to throw).

Comment: I can confirm this isn't the case, I can make changes to objects within the Student List from the MainWindow but not the Test Window.